# when I am trying to send a GET request in java servlet using Tomcat server I am getting error instantiating servlet class

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I am using tomcat version 10.0.10
This is the error I am getting when I press Submit in my index.html file
Even if I add a constructor the AddServlet is still not instantiating
I have tried to run the same code in tomcat version(apache-tomcat-8.5.61) still facing the same error.
[image: error 500]
index.html
[image: index.html]
This is the sevlet code AddServlet.java

```
package com.sintin;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



public class AddServer extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 102831973239L;
 
public AddServer() {
    
}


public void service(HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse res) throws 
IOException, ServletException {
System.out.println("in the AddServer class");
    
int x = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
int y = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));
//      String stir="sintnada";
//      PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
//      out.println("the result is"+ x+y);
        System.out.println("ans="+x+y);
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("class2");
        rd.forward(req, res);
 }
 }
```

This is the xml file web.xml inside my webapp/web-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sintin.AddServer</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>class2</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sintin.Class2</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>class2</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/class2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

[image: this is the directory of the files]

Comment: It seems like the web.xml is deployed and your compiled `AddServer` class file is not. How do you run/deploy this project?

Comment: What's the full stack trace with the root cause? The error page mentions it being in the server logs.

Comment: @nitind can u guide me on how to open server log

Comment: @f1sh I am using eclipse IDE I just right click on my project (DemoApp) hover over run as then run on the server

Answer (score 0):

when I was using JDK provided by amazon(Amazon Corretto JDK 11.0.9_12) I faced This issue.
I resolved this issue by installing java(JDK-17.0.1) by oracle and reinstalled eclipse.